# Fill height for child in Row

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I try to achieve this layout but don't really know how:

[image]

currently it looks like this:

[image]

using this Code:

```kotlin
@Preview(widthDp = 150)
@Composable
fun Item() {
    Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
        Row {
            Box(Modifier.background(Color.Yellow).weight(1f)) {
                SomeMoreContentWithUnknownHeight()
            }
            Box(Modifier.width(20.dp).height(IntrinsicSize.Max).background(Color.Green))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to set the height of the second Box to IntrinsicSize.Max but that didn't change anything. I am currently running Jetpack Compose in Version 1.0.0-beta07

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You have to apply **`Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)`** to the `Row` and the `fillMaxHeight()` modifier to the 2nd `Box`.

Something like:

```
Card(shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min) //Intrinsic measurement
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.Yellow)
                .weight(1f)
        ) {
            //Box(Modifier.height(50.dp))
        }

        Box(
            Modifier
                .width(20.dp)
                .fillMaxHeight()  //<--- fill max height
                .background(Color.Green)
        ) {
            //........
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As explained in the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements):

> The Row composable's `minIntrinsicHeight` will be the maximum `minIntrinsicHeight` of its children. The Green `Box` element's `minIntrinsicHeight` is `0` as it doesn't occupy space if no constraints are given; the Yellow `Box` `minIntrinsicHeight` will be that of the content given a specific width. Therefore, the `Row` element's height constraint will be the max `minIntrinsicHeight` of the Yellow `Box` content. The Green `Box` will then expand its height to the height constraint given by the `Row`.

Comment: Do you know why we have to apply `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to the top Row?

Comment: @AhmedHegazy, this will size the children to be as tall as the minimum height needed.

Comment: this is quite hard to understand, with `ConstraintLayout` you can just set `height` to `Dimension.fillToConstraints` (in View System just to set `height` to `0dp`) and link `top` to `parent.top` and `bottom` to `parent.bottom`, easy to understand the logic

Comment: What about this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990451/fill-height-for-child-in-row-when-one-of-them-is-constraintlayout I can't make it work with `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: basically setting `.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to container breaks logic for any `ConstraintLayout` inside this container...