# How to adjust sibling column height to fill all the space of row when this row is inside a lazy column?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In jetpack compose I have a Lazy column, and for each item I draw a row.
Each row consists of two columns. First column is about twice as the other one in height.
Now, how is the best way to tell the other column to fill all the row height - so to be equal in height with first column? This is my example code:

```
LazyColumn() {
   items(documents) {
      Row {
         Column {
            Text("One")
            Text("Two")
            Text("Three")
         }
         
         Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround) {
            Text("One")
         }
      }
   }   
}
```

Modifier.FillMaxHeight() doesn't work.
Is far as I understand that's because of using LazyColumn.

Answer (score 0):

```
verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
```

you can use this property to apply equal space.

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found it.
The answer is using
`modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` in the Row component.

As it's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67677125/fill-height-for-child-in-row)